# SharePoint 2010, Set Document To Read-Only after 48 Hours

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm a complete novice with SharePoint so I'm having difficulty framing the questions I have about the system for Google.

What I want to know is is it possible to make a document read-only after a time period (e.g 48 hours). Is this OOTB functionality or do I have to use c#?

EDIT: To be more specific, the process I want is:

1) Users create a document with a template

2) Save the document to the library

3) For 48 hours managers can edit the document they save to the library

4) After 48 Hour the document cannot be modified in SharePoint Anymore. Sure they can download it for printing but they cant change what's been saved in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a SharePoint Designer workflow. The workflow should start automatically when a new item is created (a new file uploaded).

Inside the workflow you should have a `PAUSE` activity. This should Pause for 48 hours.

The next step should use an Impersonation Step (This is required so the workflow runs with privileges to remove or update permissions of the documents). Now you can use `Replace List Item Permissions` action. In this action you can remove/update permission - So remove all FullControl/Contribute permission and only add Read Permission.

http://spcycle.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html

Answer (score 1):

It is quite great scenario for SharePoint 2010 Workflow. Here as some good things about it:

- You can achieve this functionality using SharePoint Designer
  without any programming.
- You can set workflow to start automatically
  when item created.
- In the workflow place delay activity ant set it to
  wait 48 hours.
- I believe that there is some activities in SharePoint 2010 to manage item permissions.

Here is similar sample http://spcycle.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html

Answer (score 0):

Most OOTB solution is to use retention policy for this. In the library settings you can set up such a policy.

It's simpler than workflows and makes more sense imho.

Not only can you do in place archival (preventing edits) but also multi stage archival and all sorts of usefull things to maintain a library of documents.